# Is magnetic field a consequence of electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electricity, electric-fields, electric-current

We know that magnetic field is produced by a current carrying wire with time varying current? My doubt is that- do the electrons in motion cause the magnetic field or is it due to some another reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do moving charges produce magnetic fields?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/65335/how-do-moving-charges-produce-magnetic-fields)

Comment: Have read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetism ?

Comment: The magnetic force can be understood as a relativistic effect on the electric force. It results from Lorentz transformation of the electrostatic force for a stationary charged particle

Comment: [Is there current flowing through a permeant magnet? And could we apply ampere's law for finding field of permanent magnet?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/565977/is-there-current-flowing-through-a-permeant-magnet-and-could-we-apply-amperes) and [Can magnetic force really be just electric force in a different frame?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/326728/can-magnetic-force-really-be-just-electric-force-in-a-different-frame/327222#327222)